# Double.Parse losing precision when converts 8 decimal places string

Tags: c#, .net, string, double

i am trying to convert "12345678.12345678" to double, but Double.Parse changes it 12345678.123457. Same is the case when i use Decimal instead of double

```
   decimal check = Decimal.Parse("12345678.12345678", NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint);//returns 12345678.123457
    double check1 = (Double)check; //returns 12345678.123457
```

Comment: I don't see that behavior with decimal. With double I see 12345678.1234568

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Floating point arithmetic with double precision values inherently has finite precision. There only are 15-16 significant decimal digits of information in a double precision value. The behaviour you see is exactly to be expected.

The [closest representable double precision value](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float?number=12345678.12345678) to 12345678.12345678 is 12345678.1234567798674106597900390625 which tallies with your observed behaviour.

Comment: 123.12345678 is being converted fine. i need to convert that into double to store in db, do you suggest any other data type

Comment: @jaminator You're going to lose precision if you store "12345678.12345678" in a double.  There is no way to get around that.  Anything smaller than the max decimal limit of double should be just fine with `double.parse`

Comment: `123.12345678` contains less information. Remember, double precision = 15-16 significant digits.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point types haves only so many significant digits: 15 or 16 in the case of System.Double (the exact number varies with value).

The documentation for [`System.Double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx) covers this.

A read of [*What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) is worth while.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things going on here:

1. A [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/364x0z75%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) to double conversion is inexact/the double type has precision which does not map to whole numbers well (at least in a decimal system)
2. [Double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/678hzkk9%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) has a decimal place limit of 15-16 places

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9sc2bx9h.aspx) for decimal to double conversion;

Comment: Why is decimal inexact? It can represent 12345678.12345678 exactly.

Comment: Oops.  Have that backwards.  Double is inprecise.

Comment: decimal has finite precision too. The big difference is that double is binary and decimal is, well, decimal.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for the double datatype you'll see that the precision is 15-16 digits. You've reached the limit of the precision of the type.

I believe Decimal might be what you're looking for in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick test gave me the correct value.
double dt = double.Parse("12345678.12345678");
            Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString());